# How can I manually change the approval status of list item from pending to approved/rejected?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-item, approval-process, content-approval

I've successfully used microsoft flow to automate approval workflow for modification or creation of list item. Approval, rejection all works fine.

But my manager wants to whether the approval status can also be manually changed to approved/rejected within sharepoint online only, whenever need without going to email or microsoft flow?

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Simple fix. Right clicked on the list and the option was right there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In Classic Experience:**

Follow below steps:

1. Go to List and select the item you want approve/Reject.
2. Click on **ITEMS** from top ribbon.
3. Click on **Approve/Reject**.

[image]

4. Fill the below form and Click **OK**.

[image]

**In Modern Experience:**

Follow below steps:

1. Go to List, select the item you want approve/Reject and click on ellipses(three dots).
2. Select **More**.
3. Click on **Approve/Reject**.

[image]

4. It will open similar Approval form as given in 2nd image.
5. Fill the below form and Click **OK**.

Additionally you can check the Status of list items from **Approved/Rejected items** view in Modern experience:

[image]